# 'This' checking in Jquery

Tags: jquery, this

I need to check with which element does 'this' match.
Is it possoble?

Smth like this:

```
if(this == ...) {
    alert(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($(this).is('selector')) {
    alert(true);
}
```

Where 'selector' is your typical jQuery selector, and it will return true if it matches.

Comment: You can also use $(this).hasClass('class') if that's what you're trying to find.